# for long vs. for a long time

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adverbials

> I have not heard from him **for long** or **for a long time**.

Can I use **for long** and **for a long time** in the above sentence interchangeably? Or do these phrases have different meaning and usage?

Comment: There is a good answer to this question here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/for-long-vs-for-a-long-time.1062747/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two are not interchangeable, and interestingly, they actually mean nearly opposite things.  As was pointed out in a comment, there's actually a very good [thread on wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/for-long-vs-for-a-long-time.1062747/) on this very subject.  To summarize the most important points, though:

First, "for long" can only be used in *negative* statements ("not ... for long").  On the other hand, "for a long time" can be used in both positive and negative statements.

When in a negative statement:

- "(not) for long" means that the condition actually *is* true, but it has only been true for a short time (it has *not been in the current state* very long).

> I did not have money for long, because whenever I got some, I always had to use it right away for necessities like food and rent.

- "(not) for a long time" means that the condition *is not* true, and it hasn't been true for a while (it has *not changed* since a long time ago).

> I did not have money for a long time, and I spent many months wondering where my next meal would come from.